On laptop lid shut stay suspended
I have a lap top with Ubuntu v22.04.5 LTS Mate v1.26.0 When I close the lid it suspends, but then regularly wakes up again without opening the lid (which can lead to a very hot bag, and a drained battery)
I have so far managed to emulate this by pressing the lid hard so it presses a key, and by plugging in a usb device.
Is there a setting which says "suspend on lid close, and stay suspended WHATEVER HAPPENS until lid is repoened", or some other way to achieve this.

It's my opinion that the wake is controlled by your machine firmware and not the OS itself; ie. if your machine firmware allows a specific key to wake the machine (and not others, not network activity, not lid opening etc) then tell your firmware to use that setting. The OS itself is woken by your machine firmware which awakens your hardware... ie. I'm suggesting what you need to adjust is machine make/model/firmware specific, and not the OS that is being woken up (the OS has no real control when it's suspended)

I'm not sure I have any firmware, I did a new clean install of ubuntu, are you suggesting it's in the BIOS?

The BIOS software exists on your machine as firmware.. Hardware cannot be changed, software is loaded into the machine every time you use it (from media), and your machine BIOS software is stored on chips as firmware allowing it to be used as if hardware, but also updated if required like software is..  If your machine is less than 35 years old it'll have firmware on it, esp. if PC compatible (IBM made firmware the norm in 1981)
